# Getting Event Object In Place Of Value in @Output event Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular6

Can you please help me to solve this problem. I am getting event object instead of value while sending output event from the child and listening to it parent.

Here is my code

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Hello Umashankar';
     /**
   * We can pass this dat to child component using Input 
    */
   post={
       title:"Angular Practice",
       isFavorite:false
    }
   onisFavoriteChange(isFavorite){
    console.log(isFavorite)
   }
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
     <h1>Courses Application</h1>

     <app-favorite [isFavorite]="post.isFavorite" (click)="onisFavoriteChange($event,value)"></app-favorite>
```

**favorite.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-favorite',
  templateUrl: './favorite.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favorite.component.css']
})
export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input('isFavorite') isFavorite:boolean;

   @Output() change = new EventEmitter();

   constructor() { }


   setResetFavorite(){
     this.isFavorite =!this.isFavorite;
     this.change.emit(this.isFavorite);
   }

 }
```

Comment: what are getting when you print 'e'?
i think you should get in e, as you are claling the function and passing isFavorite in the first param in child

Comment: getting event object. I need isFavorite true or false boolean value

Comment: so for both the paramerters you are getting event objects ? strange !

Comment: only for the first second is undefined

Answer (score 2):

Use output decorator name as a event name"

Output decorator name should match with output property binding

```
 @Output() data = new EventEmitter();

<app-favorite [isFavorite]="post.isFavorite" (data)="onisFavoriteChange($event)"></app-favorite>
```

**HTML**

```
  <app-favorite [isFavorite]="post.isFavorite" (change)="onisFavoriteChange($event)"></app-favorite>
```

**TS**

```
onisFavoriteChange(e){
    console.log(e)
   }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yuvgdt

Comment: I don't want event I want isFavorite value.

Comment: if you access child data through outdecorator you need to use $event.Check the example it will console the value

Comment: No data available in event

Comment: you need to use output decorator name inside the event binding syntax did you checked the example

Comment: Actually, I am new in angular. Can you please elaborate more

Comment: if you want to pass data child to parent you can use output decorator and if you want to access the emitted data in your parent component you need to use ouput property binding

Answer (score 0):

Replace `click` with `change` at `app.component.html` like this: Instead of

```
(click)="onisFavoriteChange($event,value)
```

use

```
(change)="onisFavoriteChange($event,value)"
```